# SQL request where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to have results beyond 147 but when I execute my code workbench say me Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'total_spend' in 'where clause'

```sql
SELECT
  customer_id,
  actor.first_name as first_name,
  actor.last_name as last_name,
  sum(amount) as total_spend
FROM payment
INNER JOIN actor
  ON customer_id = actor_id
where total_spend < 100
group by customer_id
order by total_spend desc;
```

Can you help me pls ?

Comment: To use a condition on an aggregate column, you need `HAVING`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `having clause`, also you cannot use the `column alias` in `where/having clause`

```
SELECT
  customer_id,actor.first_name as first_name,
  actor.last_name as last_name,sum(amount) as total_spend
FROM payment INNER JOIN actor ON customer_id = actor_id
group by customer_id
having sum(amount)<100
order by total_spend desc
```